# Compare language special character

Tags: c++

In other languages no English it is common to have a special character such as ñ in Spanish.

I have recently found myself wondering how can you compare two char such temporal == 'ñ'? Or temporal == char(-94) I have tried both and no one looks like working

Comment: The `char` type can be `signed`, `unsigned` or `char`.  If `signed`, there may not be enough range for special characters.  You may need to invest in wide characters or 16-bit values to represent the characters.  Search the internet for "c++ wide characters" or "c++ multibyte characters".

Comment: With ñ you need to understand what character set you're using.  Likely one of these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91 .  Some representations of it take up two bytes.  There's also `164` in the old "standard" extended ascii table, which is no longer standard, if it ever was, and there's "code pages" which replace it but have also fallen out of favor.

Comment: Why do you need to compare individual characters, or in general access individual characters of a string? It is almost never needed for non-text-processing applications. There is nothing special in these characters BTW.

Comment: i need to process a spanish text, and implements  a letter counter

Comment: Is this a school assignment? You should know that in Unicode accented characters can be represented in more than one way. First, as a letter followed by a separate combining accent character; and second, as a single pre-composed accented character. (Each character may occupy more than one byte). This may or may not be relevant for letter count, but it may break your word count if you are not careful.

Comment: yes, it is school assignment. Damn, then i need to rewrite all the code, there are accent and special characters

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Comment: Your assignment might be just a tad inappropriate for a school. Do they expect you to use Windows?

Comment: sup, we need to use dev c++

Comment: Then *everything* said here is probably irrelevant. UTF-8 is barely supported on Windows. You are probably expected to use a one-byte legacy code page. You need to check this with your teacher ASAP.

Comment: @n.m. - UTF16 would be "native" and definitely the easiest to work with with a new non-English app.  But yeah...the teacher might have other plans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure your most likely scenario is *you* get to choose the character set, and you have a console app.  If not, the only thing you'll want to pay attention to is the first sentence, and the `L` in front of strings in the code.  And `wchar_t` being your character type..

Make sure the project properties under `General` are set to "Use Unicode Character Set".  And also I'd forgotten a little trick with console apps.  You have to set the console mode to unicode for some bizarre reason (probably backward compatibility).  With UI apps, this is a non-issue.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
```

...

```
          _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); //use utf-16, like every other Windows system defaults to
          _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
          wchar_t n = 0x00f1;  //see https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm
          _tprintf(L"%c\n", n); //(or use wprintf explicitly)
          _tprintf(L"ññññññññññ\n");
          wcout << L"ñ\n";
```

I hope this is at least a little helpful.